# rolling polynomial regression in pandas

Tags: pandas, regression

I'm quite new to pandas here, searched but couldn't find an answer if yes or not it's feasible.

so far I'm able to calculate rolling coefficients of a simple regression `(Y= coef1 * A + coef2 * B)` like this :

```
model = pd.ols(y=df['Y'],x=df[['A','B']],window_type='rolling',window=100)
```

and model.beta returns a DataFrame of the coef1 and coef2 ..

in statsmodels I can do a polynomial regression, but there's no rolling window option:

```
poly_2 = smf.ols(formula='Y ~ 1 + A+ I(B** 2.0)', data=df).fit()
```

how could I 'mix' the 2 and have the rolling coefficients of this polynomial regression ?
I didn't see in pandas a way to write patsy-style formulas, but maybe I searched badly.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polynomial regression as illustrated is just a plain vanilla ordinary least squared regression where one of the variables has an exponent. The only thing you gain from using smf.ols (I think) is the ability to use R-esque formulas. Like that `I(B**2.0)` formula. But luckily the same logic can be built without smf and then the Pandas ols can be used.

Let's set up some example data (always a good first step when asking questions, BTW):

```
n=500
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(n), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=n))
df.columns = ['A']
df['B'] = randn(n)
df['Y'] = 5 + 3 * df.A + 6 * df.B **2 + randn(n)
```

So in this example data Y is a function of A and B^2. So we can do a windowed OLS with no polynomial:

```
pd.ols(y=df['Y'],x=df[['A','B']],window_type='rolling',window=100)
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <A> + <B> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         100
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   3

R-squared:         0.1184
Adj R-squared:     0.1003

Rmse:              9.6488

F-stat (2, 97):     6.5159, p-value:     0.0022

Degrees of Freedom: model 2, resid 97

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             A     3.8514     1.0675       3.61     0.0005     1.7592     5.9436
             B     0.0693     0.9073       0.08     0.9393    -1.7091     1.8476
     intercept    11.8889     0.9655      12.31     0.0000     9.9965    13.7813
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

But if you want the polynomial, you just create a variable that is the polynomial:

```
df['B2'] = df.B **2
```

and then you can run an OLS using B2:

```
pd.ols(y=df['Y'],x=df[['A','B2']],window_type='rolling',window=100)

-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <A> + <B2> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         100
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   3

R-squared:         0.9869
Adj R-squared:     0.9867

Rmse:              1.1748

F-stat (2, 97):  3662.8849, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 2, resid 97

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             A     2.8258     0.1304      21.67     0.0000     2.5702     3.0814
            B2     6.0091     0.0748      80.29     0.0000     5.8624     6.1558
     intercept     5.1074     0.1448      35.28     0.0000     4.8237     5.3911
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Comment: What about for orthogonal polynomials?

Comment: @tmthyjames they exist. To get a more colorful answer you'll need to ask a specific question.